# Nested rails form without accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am update a clients rails application and its rails

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.2.2'
```

and I need a nested form...any suggestions of another idea

I have user which has one profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best if it's possible to upgrade to the Rails 2.3.5 or edge (2.3.8 is a little broken with nested attributes). If this project have a good test coverage, then why not?

Else just move that logic into the controller and sleep well, because it will "just work".

Main concept of a "complex forms" you can find here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1

and also here is the "quick code":

http://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/commit/e397c44f78df34e1a6ced390dc8ee521343fae2d